# How to fetch image and pdf file from json and display in tableviewcell swift 3

Tags: json, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview

Hello all as i am a Fresher so dont know how to fetch image and pdf file from API and how to display in tableviewcell so that user can see the image and pdf file as well download it from there.I tried some code for image but its not working and dont have a single idea for pdf.Please help.

code for image :
I have declared an array of images like below :

```
var announimage : Array = [UIImage]()
```

**Below is the format of my JSON data.**

```
{
 "Download_Details": [
 {
"school_id": 1,
"class_id": "Pre - KG ",
"section": "A ",
"file_name": "427a3be0155b49db999cffb51f078f9c_431875732.pdf",
"title": "TeQ",
"message": "Hello Users",
"date": null
},
{
"school_id": 1,
"class_id": "Pre - KG ",
"section": "A ",
"file_name": "dce5ab53f45f4ec5b52894bc6286ed35_1376021.jpg",
"title": "Welcome",
"message": "Welcomes you.",
"date": null
},
{
 "school_id": 1,
 "class_id": "Pre - KG ",
 "section": "A ",
 "file_name": "9d3ff19bd54e48a087947227ee36c68c_13417773.png",
 "title": "TEST",
"message": "TEST",
"date": null
}
],
}
```

**Below is the code i have tried :**

```
let responseString = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

let downarray = responseString?.value(forKey: "Download_Details") as? NSArray

for down in downarray!
{
    let dowdict = down as? NSDictionary

    let dmsgname = dowdict?.value(forKey: "message")

    self.announmessage.append(dmsgname as! String)

   let downimage = dowdict?.value(forKey: "file_name")

   self.announimage.append(downimage as! UIImage)


}

DispatchQueue.main.async                                    
{
    self.annountable.reloadData()
}
```

**UITableView DataSource :**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! AnnounceCellTableViewCell
    cell2.announlabel.text = announmessage[indexPath.row]
    cell2.announdate.text = announcedates[indexPath.row]
    let image :UIImage = UIImage(data:announimage[indexPath.row] as! Data)!
    cell2.dataimage.image = image       
     return cell2

}
```

Comment: a UIWebView can display the pdf. and the filename needs a full url, like "http: //www.../file.png"

Comment: @deltami: Show me your tableview dataSource methods here

Comment: @Bucket Question is updated with datasource method.

Comment: let downimage = dowdict?.value(forKey: "file_name") will get only string in downimage variable i.e; "9d3ff19bd54e48a087947227ee36c68c_13417773.png" not image.

Comment: @deltami what is full URL String of image ? From which url you are getting these json response.

Answer (score 3):

```
    let imgUrlStr:String = "https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/378/378006-bigthumbnail.jpg";

    if let imgURL = URL.init(string: imgUrlStr) {
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imgURL as URL);
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData);
            print("here you will find your image:- \(String(describing: image)) ");
        } catch {
            print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Output:--

```
here you will find your image:- Optional(<UIImage: 0x6080000bca40>, {450, 338})
```

In your case get your full url by using following piece of code

```
    var prefixUrl = "http://apidomain.com/";
    let imageUrlStr = dowdict?.value(forKey: "file_name")

    prefixUrl.append(imageUrlStr);

    print("full url \(prefixUrl)");
```

**FOR PDF** -- as pdf does not display in image view, so you need to display it in webView. Just load request in webView for pdf.

```
    let webView = UIWebView.init();
    let pdfUrlStr:String = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
    let pdfUrl = URL.init(string: pdfUrlStr);
    let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: pdfUrl!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0);
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest);
```

Comment: hi @Warewolf still m getting an error now its showing index out of range.And one more thing as you coded prefixurl.append but m not able to find that method in my case its showing three methods 1)appendingPathComponent(pathComponent: String) 2)appendingPathExtension(pathExtension: String) 3) appendingPathComponent(pathComponent: String, isDirectory: Bool) among these 3 i have used pathComponent:String but not getting desired output.

Comment: hi again @Warewolf m still waiting for your help.

Comment: what is your base url (prefixUrl), your just need to add your filename after your base url of image to get full image url like  https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/378/378006-bigthumbnail.jpg

Comment: use this var prefixUrl:String = "http://apidomain.com/"; to enable append method. You are using NSString instead of String.  OR use prefixUrl.appendingFormat("%@", imageUrlStr);

Comment: hi @warewolf http://49.207.183.152:88/api/Student/Downloads?schoolid=1&studentid=1 check this APIURL once you checked plz ping me back so i can delete from here.

Comment: @deltami ask service provider what is your base url for image/pdf or xls file retrieving in json response.

Comment: you need full url for image like http://49.207.183.152:88/api/Student/Downloads/427a3be0155b49db999cffb51f078f9c_431875732.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try below code on cell for row

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(data: filteredAry[indexPath.row] as! Data)

cell2.dataimage.image = image
```

Comment: giving me the error : Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: check my updated question now its crashing at this line :                         self.announimage.append(downimage as! UIImage)

Comment: let downimage = dowdict?.value(forKey: "file_name") what you are getting here only url or uiimage ?

Comment: var announimage : Array = [UIImage]() it is not mutable change NSArray to NSMutableArray

Comment: still its crashing with error : Could not cast value of type 'Swift._EmptyArrayStorage' (0x112bfc5a0) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x1125ee548).

Comment: var announimage : Array = [UIImage]() replace with var announimage : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray ()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160833/discussion-between-bucket-and-deltami).