# What is the difference between Segue and using instantiateViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the difference between segue and instantiateViewController?

I've been trying to figure out how to use segues to send an image from one view controller to another and 2 answers ([Passing Image to another View Controller (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576232/passing-image-to-another-view-controller-swift) and [How do I segue an image to another ViewController and display it within an ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020242/how-do-i-segue-an-image-to-another-viewcontroller-and-display-it-within-an-image)) both say to use segues but when trying to use segues I encountered a few problems like the second view controller not showing up after the photo library dismissed or that the image was not showing up.

Segue example

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is XferImageViewController {
        print("Test: ", pickedImage.image)
        let xferVC = segue.destination as? XferImageViewController
        xferVC?.storedImage = pickedImage.image
    }
    print("WHAT IS GOING ON")
//        if segue.destination is XferImageViewController {
//            let xferVC = segue.destination as? XferImageViewController
//            print(pickedImage.image)
//            //xferVC?.storedImage = pickedImage.image
//            xferVC?.storedImage = pickedImageVar
//        }

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        pickedImage.image = image
    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "xferImage", sender: self)
}
```

InstantiateViewController Example

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        pickedImage.image = image
    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "xferImage") as! XferImageViewController
    controller.storedImage = image
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So after using InstantiateViewController instead of segue I got the results that I wanted. What is the difference between the two? (I made sure that that segue identifier, tried segue.destination and storyboard ID but still wasn't getting what I needed) It is possible that I don't know how to use segue after the photo library dismiss call but still want to know the difference.

Comment: Did you get any messages on the console when using segues? If so, please add that message to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the segue is particular about the state of the view controller hierarchy when you initiate the segue. You have to defer the `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` until the `dismiss` is done, namely put it into the completion handle of `dismiss`:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        pickedImage.image = image
    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "xferImage", sender: self)
    }
}
```

The above worked fine for me.

BTW, you can simplify your `prepare(for:sender:)` implementation:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let xferVC = segue.destination as? XferImageViewController {
        xferVC.storedImage = pickedImage.image
    }
}
```

---

Two somewhat unrelated observations:

1. If `pickedImage` is an image view, I'd suggest renaming it (and updating the outlets in your storyboard) to `pickedImageView`. It's a good convention to avoid confusion between `UIImage` properties and `UIImageView` outlets.
2. This is an even more minor observation, but in [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) design, you generally don't want to rely on UIKit objects, like `UIImageView` to hold model objects, namely the selected image. It suggests a conceptual confusion between "view" objects and "model" objects. Plus, what if the current view controller didn't have a `UIImageView`?

   I'd personally suggest storing the selected image in a separate `UIImage?` property:

   ```
   private var selectedImage: UIImage?

   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
           selectedImage = image

           // if you also want to update a `UIImageView` in the current
           // view controller, fine, do that, but it shouldn't be confused
           // with the "model".
           //
           // pickedImageView.image = image
       } else {
           print("Something went wrong")
       }

       dismiss(animated: true) {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "xferImage", sender: self)
       }
   }
   ```

   And:

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if let xferVC = segue.destination as? XferImageViewController {
           xferVC.storedImage = selectedImage
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: As an added note, make sure that `xferImage` is your segue's identifier and not the viewController's identifier. Since the code ran smoothly by using the same identifier with `instantiateViewController`, I'm guessing that you used the identifier for the viewController and not the segue

Comment: @Malik - Yes, I see what you mean; you don't want to confuse the segue identifier with the view controller identifier. Fortunately, if you don't have a segue with that identifier, it will generate an error telling you that, so it will be fairly obvious. But good clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation and helpful tips! I did in fact have a UIImageView in the first controller for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Function as Below

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "segue"
    {
        if let xferVC = segue.destination as? XferImageViewController {
            xferVC.storedImage = pickedImage.image

                //Why Optional here ?
                //xferVC?.storedImage = pickedImage.image
            }
        }  
  }
```